# How do I create a Line Plot Using Counted Data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, count

How would I create a line plot of quarterly orders?

Basically I have four different "counted values" that each represent total orders for a respective quarter (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4).

This data is filtered by the Marketing Channel.

So I would like to plot each quarter on the x-axis, and have the total orders on the y-axis. Meaning a plotted point would be (Q1, 300).

[link to image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBcNy.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

`plt.plot(['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4'], [count1, count2, count3, count4])`